# Connect to Proxy from different internet connection

Tags: proxy, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, proxy-server

I am creating a proxy server on my raspberry pi, connected to my home internet connection. I am wondering if it is possible to be able to connect to my proxy from a different internet connection, in a different building.

If it is possible, how would I go upon completing this task?

Answer (score 0):

This question may be too broad, but you'll need to solve the problem of getting from **outside** of your home network, to inside. You'll need forward ports on your router to allow inbound traffic. Otherwise, you could use a reverse tunnel solution.

For the port forwarding solution, you could start by researching here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

For the other solution you'll need to use a tunneling service, I use PageKite but I'm sure there are others
http://www.pagekite.net

Again, this question may get closed as "too broad", and I don't think I can really help you too much more besides pointing you in the right direction.